# How to access global variable in Angular 2 Component

Tags: angularjs, node.js, asp.net-mvc-5, typescript, google-api

I want to access google api library from angular 2 module in typescript.
How to do that.
When i try to access (gapi) i get the undefined. is there any NPM module that work as typescript library in angular 2 to which i can use or i have to use the js file.

Following is the module code and library reference:

```
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

.

```
    @Component({

    selector: "main-app",
    template: "{{title}}",
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, AuthService]

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public title: string = '';
    constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
        var gapi: any;
        console.log(gapi); // undefined
    }
    ngOnInit() {

        this._authService.getAuthSettings().subscribe((set: AppSetting) => {
            this.title = set.Scopes;
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: maybe install google api as npm if possible and then just require it.

Comment: you can probably also just export it otherwise.

Comment: require will work in asp.net mvc 5 application ?

Comment: it's commonjs, will work anywhere.  since probably you are using webpack or something similar already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have in your code :

```
    var gapi: any;
    console.log(gapi); // undefined
```

The line `var gapi` *creates a new local variable at runtime*. You don't want to create a local variable. You want to *declare* that one exists globally. Create a `globals.d.ts` file and add the following to it:

```
declare var gapi:any;
```

## More

JavaScript to TypeScript Migration guide : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Answer (score 5):

You can easily access global variables by referencing window, like so

```
gapi = window["gapi"];
```

or

```
let gapi = window["gapi"];
```